# JVM thread profiling option

Tags: java

I recall one upon a time I inputed a JVM option that printed out what each thread did after each run. I'm no longer able to find that option and Im hoping someone on SO knows what that option is.

Comment: This appears to be an [old feature that is no longer available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html).

Comment: I suggest using Flight Recorder which can dump out what every thread was doing.

Comment: @ManoDestra Yup, its the `-Xprof` option.

Comment: Worth a look: https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#JFRUH164